# Which DB is created for user when `couch_peruser` is enabled?

Tags: database, couchdb

When using CouchDB with `couch_peruser=true`, a database is created when I create a new user in the DB. My problem is that when I create a user, the response from the DB is something that looks like that:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "id": "org.couchdb.user:sergi1",
    "rev": "1-0a999e17fb6db8a0f18a32d85e08a264"
}
```

But the DB created for that user is called `userdb-736572676931`, which has no relation with the data above. I can't see data that shows the relation user/db in the changes feed either.

How can I know what database belongs to the user I just created?

Comment: Consider using Photon https://github.com/ermouth/couch-photon, it shows user name in a tooltip when you hover `user-{hexcode}`; also DB quick search shows related couchperuser DB when you enter user name in the Search input.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the link below, per-user databases are in the following form: `userdb-{hex encoded username}`.

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/couch-peruser.html